# not getting Total number of rows present in an android sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

in database.

```
public int getCnt() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOG;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();    
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null)
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}
```

also tried

```
 public long getCnt() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long cnt = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_LOG, null);
    return cnt;
}
```

in main

```
int x =0; // long for other func..
x = dbh.getCnt();  
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(x),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(x==0){
        //do some stuff
        }
    else{
        //do some other stuff
    }
```

it works but only when the table has 0 rows,
when it encounter any row i dont know what went wrong but
app stops ,, and please let me know if any other info is required

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: the second snippet needs as space between FROM and " or it will be something like
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROMTABLE_LOG`
instead of
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_LOG`

Comment: `long longForQuery (SQLiteDatabase db, 
                String query, 
                String[] selectionArgs)`
Utility method to run the query on the db and return the value in the first column of the first row.

Comment: not working!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(myColumn) FROM myTable", null);

if(cur.moveToFirst())
{
    return cur.getInt(0);
}
```

Comment: where to store the returned value and how? and it should get the total number of rows.

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst(); and int count = cursor.getCount();  This two lines are useful to you for  get a number of rows in a table. You can return count value for further use.

Comment: That's exactly what it does. Just remember to replace myColumn and myTable according your needs. The total of rows will be given by cur.getInt(0);

Answer (score 1):

First off, it is very inefficient to load the data in the rows if you simply want the count. You should use [queryNumEntries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29) if you want the count.

Comment: Not Working!!! but only when there is some content in table.